# How to get the "ctrl c" or mouse copy event in a Powerpoint 2013 Addin (developed in C#)?

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, keyhook, mousekeyhook

Code below is not trapping character type in MS Powerpoint, It does just outside of Powerpoint and how can I catch the "control copy" or "right mouse click copy" inside this code?

Code below is not trapping character type in MS Powerpoint, It does just outside of Powerpoint and how can I catch the "control copy" or "right mouse click copy" inside this code?

Code below is not trapping character type in MS Powerpoint, It does just outside of Powerpoint and how can I catch the "control copy" or "right mouse click copy" inside this code?

```
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {

        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

        private static IntPtr hookId = IntPtr.Zero;
        private delegate IntPtr HookProcedure(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        private static HookProcedure procedure = HookCallback;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProcedure lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);  


        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            hookId = SetHook(procedure);
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookId);
        }


        private static IntPtr SetHook(HookProcedure procedure)
        {
            using (Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule module = process.MainModule)
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, procedure, GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName), 0);
        }

        private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {



                int pointerCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                string pressedKey = ((Keys)pointerCode).ToString();

                //Do some sort of processing on key press
                var thread = new Thread(() => { if (pressedKey.ToLower() == "LControlKey") { MessageBox.Show(pressedKey); } });
                thread.Start();
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }


        protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
        {
            return new Ribbon();
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom ribbon.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <commands>
    <command idMso="Cut" onAction="CopyIntercept" />
    <command idMso="Copy" onAction="CopyIntercept" />
  </commands>
</customUI>

public void CopyIntercept(IRibbonControl control, ref bool CancelDefault)
{
}
```

You might be able to do this with a Ribbon Designer, but the sample above is for an XML ribbon.